# Why does a stack push cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, stack, push

How does my code actually give a segmentation fault?

I'd like to keep `TOS` as a double pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_tag{
    int num;
    struct node_tag* next;
}NODE;

void push(int x, NODE **TOS){
    NODE* temp = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp->num = x;
    temp->next = (*TOS);
    (*TOS) = temp;
}

int main(){
    NODE **TOS = NULL, *temp;
    printf("<<<Stack Push>>>\n");
    push(0, TOS);
    printf("%i\n", (*TOS)->num);
}
```

Comment: cause you're dereferencing `NULL` in this code.

Comment: `NODE **TOS = NULL` -> `NODE *TOS = NULL`,  `push(0, TOS);` -> `push(0, &TOS);`, `printf("%i\n", (*TOS)->num);` -> `printf("%i\n", TOS->num);`

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void` pointer which is automagically converted to any other type. Do not cast the return value from `malloc`, doing so can mask coding errors that the compiler might have detected for you.

Comment: @BakaBaka if your question was solved you can mark this question as resolved by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it like this;

```
int main(){
    NODE *TOS = NULL, *temp;
    printf("<<<Stack Push>>>\n");
    push(0, &TOS);
    printf("%i\n", TOS->num);
}
```